# How to convert ArrayList<String> to Float[]

Tags: android, arraylist

I have to retrieve some data from a file to show it in a chart. The function that shows the chart requires he data as `float[]` whereas the retrieved data is in the form `ArrayList<String>`.

What is the easiest way to convert `ArrayList<String>` to `float[]`?

```
        try {
            FileInputStream fIn = context.openFileInput(fileDir+fileName);
            InputStreamReader ipsr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
            BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(ipsr);

            ArrayList<String> list_prix = new ArrayList<String>();
            String ligne;

            while ((ligne = b.readLine()) != null) {
                String dtVal = ligne.split(" ")[2];
                dtVal = dtVal.substring(0, dtVal.length() - 2);
                list_prix.add(dtVal);
            }

            //just here if i can convert list_prix to float[]

            fIn.close();
            ipsr.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.e("blah", "Exception", e);
        }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)

Comment: @Charles Goodwin: Please see my edited post.

Comment: do you need list_prix after the while loop

Comment: @Nammari:Yes,exactly. After the while->loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop and use [Float.parseFloat()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat%28java.lang.String%29).

```
float [] floatValues = new float[list_prix.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < list_prix.size(); i++) {
    floatValues[i] = Float.parseFloat(list_prix.get(i));
}
```

Now, this assumes that every string in your ArrayList can actually be parsed into a float.  If not, it could throw an exception, so you may want to do this in a try/catch block if you are not sure.

Comment: I would classify this answer as "hand holding" but nevermind.

Comment: And please how to convert arraylist<string> to string[]. Looking for your response please. I've tried to change the above code to change it to String but have always an error.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < list_date.size(); i++) {
list_date.toArray(dateValues);`

Comment: Well, the string version would look pretty similar:
stringValues[i] = list_prix.get(i);  This works since list_prix is an arraylist of strings (defined by ArrayList<String>)

Comment: @Charles Goodwin: I guess it is a bit of hand holding, but we've all been there before.  A post like this might help other newbies that may not know about "parseFloat", "parseInt", etc.

Answer (score 3):

I think the following will do it using Guava...

```
Collection<Float> floats = Collections2.transform(list_prix, new Function<String, Float>() {
    public Float apply(String input) {
        return Float.parseFloat(input);
    }

});

Float[] floatArray = new Float[floats.size()];
floats.toArray(floatArray);
```

Comment: IMHO, installing Guava just for that would be like killing a fly with a nuclear bomb.

Comment: Agree with @Cristian but I voted it up as an interesting alternative :-)